# Find formula for integrals.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

First of all i know that there were a similar question:
[Evaluating $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(x)}{x^2+1}\, dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191639/evaluating-int-0-infty-frac-sinxx21-dx/281823#281823)

However i am going to ask for something different

Let there be two integrals

$I_{1}(\alpha) = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(\alpha x)}{(b+1)x^2+2ix+(b-1)}dx$

$I_{2}(\alpha)= \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(\alpha x)}{(b+1)x^2+2ix+(b-1)}dx$

Where $b$ is a complex number such $|b|<1$

> Find $I_{1},I_{2}$

Here is my attempt

I took function $f(z)=\frac{e^{i\alpha z}}{(b+1)z^2+2iz+(b-1)}$

It has poles at $z=-i$ and $z=i\frac{b-1}{b+1}$

And i took a part of a circle with two radius as a contour.
However i think it is not a good way to solve it.

Comment: Why isn't it a good way to solve it? Why don't you finish the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest way to evaluate the integrals is shown in the link you have given. I will assume $\alpha$ to be a positive real number.

Define:
$$\begin{align}
I(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\alpha x}dx}{(b+1)x^2+2ix+(b-1)}
&=\frac i{2b}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\alpha x}\left[\frac1{x+i}-\frac1{x+i\frac{1-b}{1+b}}\right]dx.
\end{align}$$
Now
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\alpha x}}{x+i}dx
=e^{i\alpha}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\alpha (x+i)}}{x+i}dx
\stackrel{t=\alpha(x+i)}=e^{i\alpha}\int_{i\alpha}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{t}dt
=e^{i\alpha}E_1(i\alpha),
$$
where $E_1(z)$ is the [exponential integral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/En-Function.html).
After similar calculation of the second term one obtains:
$$
I(\alpha)=\frac i{2b}\left[e^{i\alpha} E_1(i\alpha)-e^{i\beta} E_1(i\beta)\right],
\quad\text{with}\quad \beta=\alpha\frac{1-b}{1+b}.
$$

Finally
$$
I_1(\alpha)=\frac{I(-i\alpha)+I(i\alpha)}2;\quad 
I_2(\alpha)=\frac{I(-i\alpha)-I(i\alpha)}{2i}.
$$